# CentOS 7.7 - sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied

Tags: centos, sudo, pam, sssd

We have a CentOS 7.7 system which is joined to a Microsoft AD domain using realmd/sssd. Sudo does work perfectly fine for local system users, however when we attempt to use sudo as an Active Directory user (ocftest) we get the following error:

```
sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied
```

We are using the following version of sudo: sudo-1.8.23-9.el7.x86_64.rpm

The user can "ssh" perfectly fine to the system using their password. This issue comes up a few times after a bit of Googling, and commonly refers to adding the following to the "/etc/security/access.conf" file:

```
+ : ocftest : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

The users group with the same name (although I have tried the user) is present in the "/etc/sudoers.d/salt" file:

```
%ocftest@ad.domain.org ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

And just for completeness:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    include      system-auth

cat /etc/pam.d/sudo-i
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      sudo
account    include      sudo
password   include      sudo
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      sudo

cat /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok


password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so

cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
domains = ad.domain.org
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/ad.domain.org]
ad_domain = ad.domain.org
krb5_realm = AD.DOMAIN.ORG
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
ignore_group_members = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
enumerate = True
dyndns_update = False
auto_private_groups = true
ad_access_filter = (&(memberOf=OU=Users,OU=REDACTED,DC=redacted,DC=org))

[pam]
```

Comment: The problem may be that `pam_access.so` sees `ocftest` in `access.conf` as a local user (or group). Since it's actually in AD, you might need to qualify it with the domain name. The only examples I've seen in the wild use the `DOMAIN\user` format. The UPN `user@dom.ain` format might not work because `access.conf` uses `@` to indicate NIS netgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `no_access_check` to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (which should be a link to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`) after the first occurence of `account  sufficient   pam_vas3.so`

```
# cat system-auth-ac
...
account sufficient  pam_vas3.so no_access_check
...
```

Comment: `pam_vas3.so` is third-party software and is not used when joining to an AD domain using realmd/sssd.